# Autenticar em outra aplicação PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou logado nessa aplicação PHP , nessa aplicação possui uma listagem de usuarios conforme a imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar nesse botão **Logar** quero ser redirecionado para um dashboard que está no mesmo dominio, porém utiliza Laravel e requer autenticação conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu possuo os dados de autenticação para acessar esse dashboard, mas queria que isso fosse feito automaticamente ao clicar no botão **Logar**, teria como fazer isso usando PHP?

Comment: Você já perguntou isso nesta pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/315905/5878. Por quê criar outra? Não era mais fácil editar a original?

Comment: Exclui essa pergunta antiga.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função `login` do `Auth`, você passa o model `User` como parâmetro, desta forma:

```
public function logar_com($id)
{
        Auth::login(User::findOrFail($id));
        return redirect()
            ->action('HomeController@index');

}
```

Ao invés de buscar o `User` pelo id pode utilizar o `where` e buscar pelo email.

Comment: Uma boa também, seria legal se os usuários tivessem um token, e você recebesse ele neste método de login, para pelo token, validar o usuário e retornar para a página index com ele autenticado.

O token ajuda na questão de segurança, ficaria bacana